# lspci -v shows no Audio card

Tags: ubuntu, audio, bluetooth

My Ubuntu 18.04 device shows dummy output only. Can not connect bluetooth headphones as well, only wired headphones work.

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

gives no sound cards output.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, what hardware device do you have? What sort of system?

Comment: HP Envy 15", dualboot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. Sound works fine in windows, but on Ubuntu can only hear in type-c headphones (not on 3.5mm, bluetooth and speakers)